# Django creating model instances - Validation before creation? In manager class? What is manager class for?

Tags: django

Say I have a class "Book" and I want to hit an API to verify the book exists before creating my model.

Do I create my "BookManager" class, override create, hit the api, and throw an exception if not valid or create if valid?

Then in Book I'd write objects = BookManager()

And create a book with.

new_book = Book.objects.create(name)?

Basically, this feels like a good way to organize my code, but I'm not sure if this is intended use for the Manager class as opposed to only modifying the queryset.

Additionally, does anyone have a good reference on how to structure your django rest framework app? Folder structure etc

Answer (score 0):

I will start with very basics. I am assuming you api calls are simple get requests for now which you can achieve with python http package.

(I am assuming the api is a third party api for now)

you can define a simple view let say view name be : bookM
Next you have defined you model with lets say a primary key, book_name, other_attrs, date

now when you hit you api within this view you can get the response from get request

```
requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
```

With this if you find the response sent back with some text or null you can act on model as below :

```
book= BookSave(
   name = "book1",
   )
   book.save()
```

If this is not the case you can save error message in python variable and display while rendering html

You can use this view as api and do ajax call from web page, as well in this case you can just return back messages